# Smartedit shows legacy warning - How to prevent it?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

We generated our custom SAP Commerce Smartedit extension using the ant extgen target with the SAP Commerce Version 2105. We still get a warning in Smartedit:

```
Failed to load legacy AngularJS module CustomExtensionNameSmarteditContainer into smarteditcontainer; SmartEdit functionality may be compromised.
```

How can this be prevented? Not sure if some functionality is broken because of this legacy handling. The SAP documentation does not provide any documentation to this warning.